# For loop not working - function only getting called once

Tags: c#, function, for-loop, while-loop, opacity

I'm having some issues with my for loop. I've tried placing it in different areas and still, no luck. I'm working on a project that randomly changes the opacity of a rectangle (I have red, yellow, blue, and green). I got the project working so that it selects one color, raises opacity, waits, and then lowers opacity. However, I would like to repeat this and the loop will not.

Here is my code:

```
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }

        public void Start_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            loopthegame(5);
        }

        public void loopthegame(int amount) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                startgame();
            }

        }

        public async void startgame()
        {
                int randomcolor = RandomNumber(1, 8);
                switch (randomcolor)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Blue.Opacity = 1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Red.Opacity = 1;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Yellow.Opacity = 1;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Green.Opacity = 1;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Blue.Opacity = 1;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Red.Opacity = 1;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Yellow.Opacity = 1;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Green.Opacity = 1;
                        break;
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Blue.Opacity = 0.25;
                Red.Opacity = 0.25;
                Yellow.Opacity = 0.25;
                Green.Opacity = 0.25;
        }
```

Comment: I assume C# so I've tagged it - please correct if wrong.

Comment: When debugging, does it work? Many things don't appear to work properly on a real run, but do when debugging.

Comment: C# and debugging doesn't work either.

Comment: I suggest you get rid of these async and await.

Comment: Note that it is a very bad idea to make a new Random every time you need a new random number. Two Random objects created within the same 1/60th of a second timeslice will produce identical results. Random is seeded off the clock, and the clock only ticks 60 times a second.

Comment: Avoid `async void`. I wrote [an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) recently explaining why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your async should be slightly updated:

```
public void loopthegame(int amount) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        Task<int> t = startgame();
        await t;
    }

}
//...
public async Task<int> startgame()
{
     int randomcolor = RandomNumber(1, 8);
     switch (randomcolor)
     {
          case 1:
              Blue.Opacity = 1;
              break;
          //...
          case 8:
              Green.Opacity = 1;
              break;
      }
      await Task.Delay(1000);
      Blue.Opacity = 0.25;
      Red.Opacity = 0.25;
      Yellow.Opacity = 0.25;
      Green.Opacity = 0.25;

      return randomcolor;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to add "async" to the loopthegame() function.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to do your async right (a slight modification):

```
    public async void loopthegame(int amount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            // this 
            await startgame();
        }
    }
```

Also:

```
    public async Task startgame()
    {
       //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually in your random number generator. When you create a random number generator with no seed (new Random()), it uses time as the seed. This runs fast enough that you're using the same seed every time, so RandomNumber returns the same number every time. Instead of creating a new Random every time, you should have one Random that you use multiple times. Create one in your constructor/main method, and use it repeatedly in your RandomNumber method.

This is easily tested with this bit of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(random.Next(1, 8));
}
```

Try it out, it will print the same value five times.